# "Comment" out Macro Function Definition

Tags: c++, googletest, c-preprocessor

I am trying to use GTest to test my code but one of the things that bothers me is that it always gets compiled in.  This slows down my release builds.  A GTest test looks like this

```
TEST(CaseName, TestName)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(3, 3);
}
```

I want to be able to comment out all of my test by a simple define.  I can wrap every test in `#ifdef`'s but that is really ugly.  I would like to not include the GTest headers and instead define TEST myself in a way to get rid of the test.

## What I Have So far.

I have a macro that defines it as a static function so that it should get optimized out but the `assert`'s inside the test still get compiled (and are undefined).  This means that I would also have to define every `ASSERT` and `EXPECT` which is tedious to say the least.

```
#define TEST(tcase, test) static void uselessFunction##tcase##_##test(void)
```

I *could* stick with this but I would much prefer something nicer.  Hopefully there are some macro-magicians out there to help.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel - what is wrong with assert and the NDEBUG #define?

Comment: This is what I was going but GTest has some nice features, such as automatic running, nice printing (being able to see the actual values is killer).  I was using `assert`'s and a script that scanned my sources for specially formatted test names (so I didn't have to keep a list) but GTest is a lot nicer.

Comment: sounds fair - I liked cppunit - but I think it may be a bit outdated today. Though on a modern machine compile time should be your last worry. Forward defs of classes can help speed things but I compile 100,000's of lines of code in less than a minute now. CPU time is the cheapest thing on the planet

Comment: I'm not so much worried about compile time as runtime.  You compile once and run often (if you're a user).

Comment: totally agree - but until you perform performance testing and prove it is an issue - ignore it. Programmers (especially experienced ones) are the worst people to perform optimizations - trust your tools - they can do a better job then you and if you are serious perform runtime testing and recompile with the results of the tests to help the compiler.

Comment: @KevinCox: I am not sure what you really want. The question seems to indicate that you want to reduce compile times (have you thought of just not compiling the tests?), but the comment says that you are more concerned about runtime (are you running the tests or the application? why/how do the tests interact with the application runtime?)

Comment: I know that it is probably insignificant and I shouldn't care but the test set themselves up and that slows the executable start time and takes more memory.  It also makes a bigger executable and requires that an extra library be linked.  It's not major it would just be nice to avoid.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Ideally I would completely remove all test code and I wouldn't have to link libgtest at all.

Comment: @KevinCox: I don't think it is a good idea to have the tests built into the product, you should really work on that, as there is no reason for the tests (development) to get to production at all. Adding extra code to the binary is not going to help in any way and it might actually hurt (say there is a bug in your tests and they allocate a bunch of memory that is never freed, then the tests would be interfering with the proper use of resources in the product...)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using macros like this, it might be better to put all your tests into files which are compiled into a test executable, and put all your production files into a library which is linked by the test exe.

In this way, you can have gtest run against both Debug and Release builds, but only compile the test code when you build the test executable.

Comment: I could do that but I would prefer to have the test right beside the source.  It is easier to ensure that proper test are written.  The only difference between the two scenarios is that you have them in separate files while I have them inline.  We are both using the same process otherwise.

Comment: It's not really the same process.  You can exclude the tests from compilation for *all* configurations the way I suggest, or more importantly, you can include them for all configurations.  Disabling the ability to run the test suite in Release is not something I would choose to do.  Some errors can only really be invoked by running the Release code.

Comment: I can run the test suite in release.  My test define is different than my release define.  The test can be run on either.  If you mean on the final build than fair enough, but I was/am careful to ensure the tests are the only thing to change (I take that risk).